# Can i go to the error after executing make in VIM?

Tags: c++, c, vim, makefile

Can i go to the line of error , while compiling a `C or C++` project ? Usually by executing `make` , and parse the error string , and go to the specific file , and the line with errors.

Is there already an usable plugin ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yeah this is already buit into vim. After typing `:make` type `:cwindow` to bring up the error list. You can then navigate to the errors using this window.

Comment: and how can i went through different errors generated by VIM ?

Comment: For newcomers reading this answer and looking at daisy's question, to alternate between the error list and the code, use ctrl-w + w or ctrl-w twice.

Answer (score 17):

You can as well after `:mak` or `:make` do `:cope` to open the window with compiler output and once you are done `:clo` to close it.

Use `:cn` and `:cp` for jumping to next and previous error or when you are in the window go to line that has the error with file name, line & column and press enter to jump there.

Comment: `:cope` - nice one to remember. Although `:cwindow` abbreviates to shorter `:cw`. If there were few errors, `:cn` usually suffices.

Answer (score 6):

IIRC, this functionality is built into vim.  A quick google search revealed this [useful link](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html).  This describes vim's features for navigating the errors after a make.